# React-native and VS code

Tags: javascript, react-native, visual-studio-code

What do I have to do to see the information (property/method...) of a library in VS Code?

(I'm using the framework: React-native, language: JavaScript)

**Currently I can't see anything** *(see image below)*
[image]

**What I wanted** (example image taken in Android Studio)
[image]

**Thank You!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Windows**: By holding `ctrl` and hovering to the `<View />` you can see more info

**Mac**: Hold `CMD` and hover to the `<View />`

**Try installing this extension and restart your VS Code (For additional support),**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If youre using a mac or macos,

just press CMD and hover over View tag or any other tag, youll see the details :)

Answer (score 0):

You could install "ES7+ React/Redux/React-Native/JS snippets" in VSCode extension's menu or in the following link: [ES7+ React/Redux/React-Native/JS snippets](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dsznajder.es7-react-js-snippets)

after you install it, restart VSCode by pressing **ctrl+shift+p**, and type "*Restart extension Host*", this will allow you to restart extensions without closing your project and/or the IDE.